# A lock database was not specified with the DAVLockDB directive. One must be specified to use the locking functionality. [500, #401]

Tags: php, maven, web, apache2, webdav

I am trying to deploy my maven project website using WebDAV protocal into apache 2.2. Server.

And When I am deploying the application to the server, I am getting above error.

I have following configuration in `httpd-dav.conf`. but I am still finding above error in ahache_error.log file. Could anybody help me to find the reason here.

```
DavLockDB "c:/apache2.2/var/DavLock"
Alias /sites "c:/apache2.2/sites"

<Directory "c:/apache2.2/sites">
    Dav On

    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all

    AuthType Digest
    AuthName DAV-upload

    Options Indexes

    AuthUserFile "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/user.passwd"
    AuthDigestProvider file

    # Allow universal read-access, but writes are restricted
    # to the admin user.
    <LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
        require user admin
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the answer after 2 days and answer is very simple.

I removed DavLockDB `"c:/apache2.2/var/DavLock"` from httpd-dav.conf file and 
placed this line inside httpd.conf file

This is the only change I did and now I am able to access apache2.2 server using web dav protocal.

Answer (score 0):

Works OK also on Windows.

I have been with the same problem connecting from GoodReader on Ipad to a WebDav on Windows 10 with Laragon.

code C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15\conf\httpd.conf

Added the line under WebDAV Apache modules:

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
DavLockDB "C:/www/webdav/DavLock"
```